# SignalR - System.Numerics.Vectors v4.1.4 not found when using AspNetCore.SignalR.Client nuget package

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to follow the pattern shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492131/aspnetcore-signalr-cannot-start-a-connection-that-is-not-in-the-initial-state).

where I'm using:

```
HubConnectionBuilder()
```

in my WPF client app (.NetFramework 4.7). To do this, it seems to me I need to add a reference to:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
```

in my WPF app.

However, I'm getting this error when I try to build:

> ```
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

Am I including the right package for WPF? Or should I be trying to solve the missing file issue? If the latter, how to I get the right file into my build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've seen this particular problem.
As I recall this is "just" a problem in the nuget package dependencies.

Try adding a manual reference to System.Numerics.Vectors

Comment: That didnt work for me (VS2017), i added 4.5.0 via NuGet and didnt make any difference.

Comment: Sometimes the issue is that the assembly is actually correct, but there is a wrong (old, leftover) `<bindingRedirect>` setting in the .config file which then causes the issue. I had this same problem and it turned out that the .config file in the release folder wasn't being updated on rebuild. In my case, restarting VS (it was a preview version) fixed this, but in any case I would try reinstalling the package through NuGet, check all projects in the solution to ensure they all reference the same version, and then cleanup the release folder and double check the .config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.5.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
```

(.NET 4.7.2)