# Deserializing json integers to longs results in exceptions and null values, seemingly randomly

Tags: json, servicestack

I have the weirdest problem that suddenly occurred:

In some (many) cases, suddently, parsing a DTO that contains `long` fails, depending on the value of the `long`. Let's look what happening. I am using ServiceStack and Visual Studio 2017, .NET Framework 4.7.2.

The service

```
[Tag("Notifications")]
[Route(Misc.BASE_PATH, "PUT")]
public class SetActorNotificationsRead : IReturn<SetActorNotificationsReadResponse>
{
    public List<string> NotificationIds { get; set; }
    public List<string> Test { get; set; }
    public long MyLong { get; set; }
}
```

and I call this via Postman, like this:

[image]

in this case, it works as expected, the DTO is populated correctly:

[image]

If I change MyLong to 123**4**, it fails with a

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors

[image]

but if I change it to 123**45**, it works again:

[image]

To make matters worse, if I change the NotificationIds to a `List<long>`, it gets even weirder:

This Postman call fails, since the NotificationIds list is null:

[image]

[image]

but if I change the request, and add a zero in front of the four 9:s, then it works:

[image]

[image]

If I do `[ 9999, 123 ]`, the `NotificationIds` is still null, but if I do `[ 09999, 123 ]`, or `[ 99991, 123 ]` its not null and both values are in the list.

I'm clueless. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the Exception due to a runtime dependency issue where it can't load 'System.Numerics.Vectors' assembly.

You can try [adding a manual reference to System.Numerics.Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49943288/85785).

From package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors

Comment: Thanks, but that didnt work. I added that ref via NuGet, version 4.5.0, but the exact same behaviour =(

Comment: @Ted ok but that's the issue that needs solving, as it's a runtime dependency issue I'd try cleaning out all binding redirects and re-installing packages, if that fails try googling for solutions, e.g. I've found this [potential fix](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30106#issuecomment-395185748).